# Is it Possible to Static Test With a Barbecue Lighter?

Tags: embedded, esd, static

I'm working on an issue with a product where it freezes due to static shocks.

I'm trying to recreate the issue and harden the product, but I don't have a real static testing wand like the test labs use.

As a substitute, I took a barbecue lighter and connected the barrel to ground, and cut the shroud off the end so the inner spark contact is exposed. This recreates the issue reliably, but I suspect the spark is actually *too powerful*, such that it may be basically impossible to protect against.

I would like to do 2 things and I'm not sure how to proceed:

1. Attenuate the spark, using some kind of impedance network such as a resistor divider.
2. Measure the voltage or current pulse using an oscilloscope. I don't have any exotic probes, so I would like to build another attenuator for this purpose.

Using a device other than a barbecue lighter is also an option if it will work better. I just can't buy any multi-thousand dollar equipment for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "static test"? Do you mean a standard test for ESD, or just a seat-of-the-pants rough test?

Comment: I mean: applying static discharges to the device to see if it malfunctions. It's already passed CE testing but one of the techs was able to cause a static issue on a very static-ey day so I would like to add even more protection. I need a way to test the results.

Comment: A weeks hire of a proper ESD gun ain’t gonna cost much.

Comment: If I can build something similar (but worse) that gets the job done I'd rather do that. If that's not practical then yes I might just rent an ESD gun.

Comment: it is `electrostatic discharge test`

Comment: 12 volt battery, an ignition coil, an oscillating relay and a spark plug is the BoM. The wire feeding the spark plug is the emitter. Test with that rather than trying to force a spark onto the equipment. Drape the wire over the equipment.

Comment: @andyaka I think that will produce EMI, but no ESD.